# I've come on business

Tags: sentence-choice

Ok,let's create a scenario. Imagine you're talking to an immigration officer in a foreign country and he / she asks you "Why are you here?"

Would these three responses make sense?

> I've come on business.
> I've come for business.
> I've come for holidays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They would make sense.  There is very little difference between "on business" and "for business".  The first one (on business) suggests that your business in you home country sent you.  The second one (for business) suggests that your purpose is to find business in the foreign country.

You can also say "on holiday" and "for a holiday" or (perhaps "for holidays", but that is a little odd). Again there is very little difference.

Obviously you shouldn't say "for a holiday" if you are on business!

Answer (score -1):

"I've come to do business" could be more assertive, which is important with immigration; to be very brief, clear and unambigious!

I don't think 'business' is all that clear, so maybe stating what exactly the business to be done is would be preferable. It invites additional questions if you are too cryptic. (I have come to negotiate a business offer (regarding ...) (with ...) depending on what they need to know) But hey, if you get through you get through!